# Cassandra datastax @Entity-annotated class must have at least one property defined

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have below Entity class used Datastax java driver 4.1.x

```
package com.xyz;

import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.CqlName;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.Entity;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.PartitionKey;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Xyz {

    @PartitionKey
    @CqlName("id")
    private Integer id;

    @CqlName("name")
    private String name;

    @CqlName("description")
    private String description;
}
```

While doing mvn clean package/mvn clean install, getting below error (not compiled Entity class)

**[Xyz] @Entity-annotated class must have at least one property defined.**

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I am using Datastax driver 4.15.0. Annotation processing is enabled in Intellijl. Looks like there is an issue with Lombok and datastax. Intellij can be one of the reasons. I removed the following
`@Getter`
`@Setter`
`@NoArgsConstructor`
`@AllArgsConstructor`

Generated vanilla getters,setters and constructors and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is to include the below config in my pom:

```html
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>com.datastax.oss</groupId>
                            <artifactId>java-driver-mapper-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${cassandra-java-driver-core.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

It may be better to use @Data for mutable objects or @Value for immutable types.
With the addition of the above in my pom, this worked for me:
You can find more about this in the datastax documentation:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.10/manual/mapper/config/lombok/

```html
@Entity(defaultKeyspace = "mykeyspace")
@CqlName("tableName")
@Data
public final class SomeEntity {

    @PartitionKey
    @CqlName("theid")
    private String someId;

    @CqlName("someUdtTableColumn")
    private tableColumn thetableProperty;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In gradle, it seems like the annotation processors are processed in sequence.  I defined the lombok annotation processor before the scylla annotation processor and it worked.

Works:

```
//lombok
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"

//Scylla
annotationProcessor "com.scylladb:java-driver-mapper-processor:$scyllaDriverVersion"
```

Doesn't work:

```
//Scylla
annotationProcessor "com.scylladb:java-driver-mapper-processor:$scyllaDriverVersion"

//lombok
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:$lombokVersion"
```